# Color is equal to another color, Java

Tags: java, colors, equals

Okay the color I have set in the variable C is equal to the variable in coal1, but when put through an if statement it comes back that they are not equal. I've debugged it with print lines and the result is weird to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Code

```
class MyTask extends TimerTask {

    static Color coal1 = new Color(255, 255, 255);
    Robot robot;
    int xRock, yRock;

    MyTask(Robot r, int x, int y) {
        this.robot = r;
        this.xRock = x;
        this.yRock = y;
    }

    public void run() {
        java.awt.Color c = this.robot.getPixelColor(this.xRock, this.yRock);
        System.out.println("c before the if: "+c);
        System.out.println("coal 1 before the if: "+coal1);

        if (c.equals(coal1)) {  //I can not get the c from the other class to compair with coal1
            System.out.println("color is the same");
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("c after the if: "+ c);
            System.out.println("coal1 after the if: "+coal1);
            System.out.println("color changed");

            //Stop Timer.
            this.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it i get

```
c before the if: java.awt.Color[r=225,g=225,b=225]
coal 1 before the if: java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
c after the if: java.awt.Color[r=225,g=225,b=225]
coal1 after the if: java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
color changed
```

Comment: I don't recall Java well enough, but I suspect `c.equals(foo)` only returns true if `c` and `foo` _are the same object_, which is not what you want.  You want to know if `c` and `foo` have the same set of values.

Comment: They ... aren't equal. `255` != `225`, @DanPichelman - that is completely incorrect (you have it backwards, `==` compares reference values)

Comment: @BrianRoach - you have better eyes than I do.  I completely missed that.  Great call; my bad.

Answer (score 5):

According to your output, they are not the same. `c`'s red, green, and blue components are 225, while `coal1`'s components are 255.

`Color.equals(Color o)` compares the RGB values which in your case are not the same

Answer (score -1):

Here's the solution I've come up with:

```
int R = 255; 
int G = 255; 
int B = 255;
if ((c.getRed() == R) && (c.getGreen() == G) && (c.getBlue() == B)) { 
    System.out.println("Found color"); 
} else { 
    System.out.println("Couldnt find color"); 
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted in the first place and it is producing the correct results.

Answer (score -3):

Try using the instanceof operator.

Comment: **WHY???** For what purpose?

Comment: Cause it would work...

Comment: @MartinEstes *How* does using the `instanceof` operator work in this situation? You typically need to provide more information when writing answers. Also, there's an option to delete your answer.